# jquery jqplot charts

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am trying jquery jqplot charts,

here is my code for the same,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart3', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="chart3" name="chart3" style="width:400px; height:300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

it gives javascript error that object cannot support this property or method, can anyone please guide me on this, 
anybody's help will be highly appreciated,

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should use either minified java script file or non minified js files. do not use both.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove line number 10 from that code.

You've included the jquery.min.js file after including jqplot on line 10. jquery.min.js recreates the jQuery object (removing the jqplot function) and needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include files in order of dependency.  Jqplot depends on jQuery, so jQuery should be listed first, and only include one instance of each.  You are including multiples of just about every file there.

You may want to learn the basics of JavaScript before you try to used advanced plugins.

Comment: thanks for your help, and yes i am going through the basics, can you recommend a good source?

Answer (score 0):

[Eric : Refer this site. it simply says all the things regarding to jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/)

[Eric : Refer these blog also](http://springjquery.blogspot.com/)

Comment: When you post an external link, it helps to document the key points here so that the crux of the post is available even if the link goes down.